# android process still alive after finishing activities

Tags: android, process, android-activity

My application launches 3 activities.
When I want to exit, I close these 3 activities calling finish method. The activity onDestroy methods are then called but the process is still alive...
How is it possible ?

Comment: Did you make sure to clean up everything in your onDestroy() callbacks? Make sure you unregister for content providers, etc. and close all of your connections.

Comment: does your activity contain any service

Answer (score 8):

This is perfectly normal. Android will keep your process around until such time as it needs to reclaim that process' memory. That way, if the user immediately returns to your application, your application will appear quicker -- Android does not have to fork a process and load your application into memory.

Comment: The problem is that I have many static variables !! When the user come back to my application, they are in a undefined state.

Comment: I need to kill my process properly whjen the user exit application

Comment: @Arutha: No, you don't. You need to do a better job of coding. There is no guarantee, at any point, whether static data members will exist or not. This has nothing whatsoever to do with whether or not you call `finish()`, as there are many other scenarios in which the user will abandon your application and Android will get rid of your activities (e.g., user presses HOME and does not return). If you are going to use static data members, you have to deal with the case whether they exist or they do not exist. If you cannot do that, do not use static data members.

Comment: There's really no way to force to kill the current process ?

Comment: @Arutha: Not in a way recommended by Google. And, as I indicated, even if you did, it would not help. Please fix your app so that it works properly in all cases.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi, like you said in above comment, 'there is no guarantee whether static data members will exist or not'. So, these members persist even if we exit (press back from launcher activity) app?

Comment: @Darpan: Static data members exist so long as the process does. A process may only live for millliseconds once it moves into the background. If you want to *persist* data, write it to a *persistent* place: database, `SharedPreferences`, or some other form of file.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. This has been a puzzle for me for days.

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
System.exit(0);
```

It will kill your Activity-process.

**Edit:**
As mentioned in the comments below. This works much better:
    *android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());*

Comment: There are many reason to avoid using System.exit(0) in our apps... but "android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());" works better...

Comment: Didn't know it. Thanks!

Comment: Why does it work better? I didn't find any difference in effect of System.exit vs. killProcess.